# R.array doesn't show in the list after I type R

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am getting this R.array error. It doesn't show in the list after I type R. I tried deleting `R.java` but still not working

```
private void openNewGameDialog() 
    {
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Choose a Category").setItems(R.array.category, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() //alert dialog which will show list of categories to select
              { 
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) 
                   {
                      startGame(i);
                   }
              }).show();
     }
```

Comment: Be sure to build your project so that R.java is generated and compiled to R.class under your bin directory. (Are you using Eclipse or the command-line?)

Comment: eclipse helios @Code-Guru

Comment: Please show the XML file where you declare the "category" string array.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="category">
<item>Plant</item>
<item>Animal</item>
<item>Insect</item>
</string-array>
</resources>

Answer (score 2):

If there are any errors in any of the xml files in the android project, the R file will not generate itself. This might be part of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`R.array.category` this is just a constant, represents category array in your Strings.xml,

You need to pass Array to the SetItems.

so what you need to do is to get the String array.

`getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category);` as a argument to the setItems.

i.e

```
setItems(`getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category)`, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
```

Comment: stll not happening @pragnani :(

Comment: @NiksChodankar Your previous one is also right...I am wrong it will accept id also, as I have just go throgh the documentation..

Comment: @NiksChodankar check in problems is there any problem, because R.java won't generate when your project have any errors.

Comment: as far as i knw no errors in xml file.... Deleted the R.java file... still no use..

Comment: @NiksChodankar Make sure that you are not importing `android.R.java`, remove any import in your activity with `R.java` and clean your project once

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to build your project so that R.java is generated and compiled to R.class under your bin directory. Even if it doesn't show up in your autocomplete suggestions, you can still type it manually. If you save the project and still get a compiler error (a red underline), then come back and tell us what the error says and we can help you from there.

Comment: as far as i knw no errors in xml file.... Deleted the R.java file... still no use.. still the same red line coming.. @code-guru

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project.